# Sending Long Message form pc to mobile in VB6

Tags: vb6, sms, mscomm32

I want to send long sms (more than 160 characters) from pc to mobile. I am using MSComm control in VB6. It works good with small messages but when my message exceeds 160 characters then it shows sending ok but message is not delivered.

```
With MSComm1
    .CommPort = port
    .Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
    .Handshaking = comRTS
    .RTSEnable = True
    .DTREnable = True
    .RThreshold = 1
    .SThreshold = 1
    .InputMode = comInputModeText
    .InputLen = 0
    .PortOpen = True 'must be the last
End With

'Send an 'AT' command to the phone
MSComm1.Output = "AT" & vbCrLf
Sleep 500
MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf 'This line can be removed if your modem will always be in Text Mode...
Sleep 500
MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & mnumber & Chr(34) & vbCrLf  'Replace this with your mobile Phone's No.
Sleep 1000
MSComm1.Output = TxtMessage.Text & Chr(26)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send a message that exceeds the 160 character limit.

When your phone receives a long message its actually receiving multiple messages and stitching them together, this is called *Concatenated SMS*.

To do this you would need to switch from *Text Mode* (how you are currently interacting with the device) to *PDU* mode; this enables you to manually set the SMS  message header (UDH).

Within the UDH you can set a flag (IEI) indicating that the message is a concatenated SMS, the total number of parts and the current part number. You can then send multiple short messages and rely on the receiving end sticking them together.

Comment: I read some Tutorials about PDu mode , but fails to edit my above code , Please if give me some instruction to change my above ocde